# AT3IONT3-I Boot from USB

Tags: live-usb, boot-failure, bios, sata

I'm trying to get my HTPC I've built to run ubuntu. For some reason, when I try to boot from USB I get this weird graphical error. Tweaking the bios a little more tells me that it can't find anything to boot off from my USB drive. I've followed the instructions on ubuntu.com (for mac) when you download an ISO.

Here's a video of what I'm doing: http://vimeo.com/29318791

Edit:
I now have ubuntu booting from a harddrive after a CD install. However, now I get dropped into initramfs, and get lots of these: `ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=16)`  what now?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem with the driver/resolution/refresh-rate.  Try using the VESA driver and see if it helps.  Details [here](http://spblinux.de/2.0/grub.htm).

Comment: But I don't even get to the grub menu, so how can I modify these values?

Comment: it's a hellish solution(like you would have to do it after every kernel update), but just edit menu.lst, rerun updage-grub, and wait while your screen is borked during boot.  this would have to be done on another PC

Comment: btw, i really think it's refresh rate

Comment: I've managed to get it to boot from harddrive after a CD install, but I keep getting ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=16) what now?

Comment: different problem.  new question.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62295/ata2-comreset-failed-errno-16