# COMRESET failed errno=-16 While Starting Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: boot, 15.04, disk

I restarted my laptop and it seems like I cannot get it to start. I get the error message `ata2: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)`, and `Busybox` as picture illustrates:

[image: IMG:]

Comment: refer same thread here http://askubuntu.com/questions/62295/how-to-fix-a-comreset-failed-error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Just type

```
exit
```

in the box and it might start up.

I have to do this everytime I start up my computer. If anyone else has a fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched for the same problem and finally found the culprit of this error! Whenever you using your Western Digital hard drive you have to run it
jumperless ( for master only ) or for using it with any SATA-to-IDE adapter
If you are not using any adapter, make sure you slave hard drive is connected properly and found! Otherwise this error will always shows up. Also causing bad CRC when writing to disk :(