# Radeon VCE init error (-22) - can't boot system

Tags: boot, radeon

I had a big problem tonight considering booting system on Ubuntu 16.04. While working, my system suddenly stopped and showed grey screen. After trying to reboot the computer, the error is shown.

[image: That's the photo of a problem which occurs]

Has someone experienced a similar problem and has an idea how to solve it?

Unfortunately fcsk doesn't solve the problem.

PS. after few trials my computer crashed totally and the screen doesn't even show anything. So I assume that may be a hardware problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix a COMRESET failed error?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/62295/how-to-fix-a-comreset-failed-error)

Comment: This does not work for me. After typing exit it just brings me back to the same menu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Welcome to emergency mode!" Think it is a fsck problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/646414/welcome-to-emergency-mode-think-it-is-a-fsck-problem)